# xpath only grabbing HTML comment within tags

Tags: php, html, xpath, curl, comments

I have a php script that logs into a website, and then I'm trying to run an xpath query to grab a certain tag.  If I save the page locally and run the xpath, then everything works out great; however, when I log into the site and run the xpath, it only returns the html comment at the bottom of the tag.  So - if I have:

```
<html>
    <body>
        something here
        <!--comment here-->
    </body>
</html>
```

and I point my xpath query at //html/body, it will only return "comment here" and nothing else.

I'm VERY confused and have never seen anything like this - any ideas?

EDIT: here's my php after the curl login (which is successful) - it's pretty standard:

```
$file = REDACTED;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//html/body/div[1]");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $out = $node->nodeValue;
    }
  }
}

echo $out;
```

Comment: You need to show your PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You're saving your nodes incorrectly:

```
$out = '';
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    foreach ($element->childNodes as $node) {
        $out .= $doc->saveHTML( $node);
    }
}
```

Your original problem is this:

```
$out = $node->nodeValue;
```

Where `$out` kept getting overridden on every iteration, so you'd only get the last value. The solution above continuously concatenates the values of the nodes, so you'll get all of them.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 provides `comment()` function for accessing comments within an XML file. Just append this function to the node from which you want to fetch comments.

For below input xml fragment

```
<html>
    <body>
        something here
        <!--comment here-->
    </body>
</html>
```

XPath would look like

```
/html/body/comment()
```

This should fetch you text `comment here`.
For more information refer [**this**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-matching-item).